# Direct limit of completions of finitely generated submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, formal-completions

Let $A$ be a **noetherian, local, integral domain** with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. Moreover let $M$ be an $A$-module; I'd like to know if there exists an explicit expression of the module:
$$\varinjlim_{N\subseteq M} \widehat N$$
where $N$ varies among the finitely generated $A$-submodules of $M$ and $\widehat N$ is the $\mathfrak m$-adic completion of $N$.

In particular what happens if $M$ is already finitely generated?

---

I'm asking this question because it is well known that
$$M\cong \varinjlim_{N\subseteq M}  N$$
so I'm interested in the behavior of the completions with respect to the direct limit.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

For finitely generated modules the completion functor is isomorphic to $-\otimes_{A} \hat{A}$ and direct limits commute with tensor products, so you get:

$
\varinjlim\limits_{N\subset M} \hat{N}\cong \varinjlim\limits_{N\subset M} (N\otimes_{A}\hat{A}) \cong (\varinjlim\limits_{N\subset M} N)\otimes_{A} \hat{A}\cong M\otimes_{A}\hat{A}\cong \hat{M}
$

Comment: Can you give a reference for the sentence: ''For finitely generated modules the completion functor is isomorphic to $−\otimes_A\widehat A$ ''

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(algebra)). You'll also find the statement in every introductory algebra book that treats completions.